# Laravel update record with Passport

Tags: api, laravel-5, token, updates

Hi all today i have this problem with my api.
I don't update the record on DB. 
In postaman the response is true but don.t save in db.
In Postaman i passed with PUT method and set in Body name a text

ProductController:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $product = auth()->user()->products()->find($id);

    if (!$product) {
        return response()->json([
            'success' => false,
            'message' => 'Product with id ' . $id . ' not found'
        ], 400);
    }

    $updated = $product->fill($request->all())->save();

    if ($updated)
        return response()->json([
            'success' => true
        ]);
    else
        return response()->json([
            'success' => false,
            'message' => 'Product could not be updated'
        ], 500);
}
```

[image: Postman Update Api]

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at your `Product` Model to see if name is set as a fillable field:  `$fillable = ['name'];`. Also, the key is probably just `name` instead of `"name"`.